# Hibernate and Inheritance - need to add one additional column (Spring Boot)

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, nhibernate-inheritance

I have table A:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "A")
public class A{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "message_id")
    private Message;
}
```

I have a table Message:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="message")
@Getter
@Setter
public class Message{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "account_id", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "FK_account_to_message"))
    private Account account; //and then search by Account.id
}
```

In my service I get all A objects by:

```
List<A> aObjects = ARepository.findByMessage_Account_Id(user.getId())
```

So I want to get all `A` objects which have such `Message` fields that `Message` fields have such `Account` fields that `Account.id == user.getId()`

Now I have additional type of `A` entity - without any relation to `Message` because now object A can be created by uploading an Excel file (reading data from a file and saving in database, so in this case we don't have `Message` data that can be added in `Message` column). So I have to store new `A` objects in `A` table but with empty column `Message` BUT with additional column -> `user_id` -> currently that's the parameter to find all `A` objects (`ARepository.findByMessage_Account_Id(user.getId())`)
The question is how/where to store `A` objects that differ in `Message` column (empty, no relationship to Message table).

I thought about `Single Table Inheritance` with `Discriminator value` but in this case when I want to find all `A` objects by user_id I would have to prepare one bigger select like: `get all A objects from A where A.Message.Account.id = user_id or A.user_id = user_id`.

Is it a good approach? Or maybe should I use something different?

Comment: It's difficult to answer the question without knowing the business context. However, wouldn't the simplest solution be to add `userId` (or an association to the `User` entity) to `A`, and simply accept the fact that some `A`s will have no associated `Message`, while others will have no associated `User`?

Comment: As far as the business context goes: let's say you add a `B` entity with `userId` and no association to `Message`. Do `A` and `B` have *different behaviours*? Are there any use cases when only using `B` makes sense? Or is `A` as good as `B` in every context? If that's the case, it doesn't make sense to have separate entities

Comment: Just sometimes A objects are created from Excel file and then we don't have Message data that we could add to the column Message when creating A object. SOmetimes A object is created from reading an email (and then we have Message data to save in Message column... That's it). Additionally user_id is the currently logged user so mabye you're right that I should only add new column user_id to A table. But then what sql query should I prepare to get all A objects for some specific user_id...

Comment: You'll need something similar to the one you mentioned, with an `OR` statement. There's no way around it, though, inheritance or not. You could also consider simply populating `user_id` from the `Message` (if present), reducing the number of conditions to just one. This, of course, introduces redundancy, but the redundancy is only harmful when the `Message.account` and `userId` fields can change (because then `Message.account.userId` and `userId` could go out of sync), and judging from the source for the `Message` field, I'm assuming they can't

Comment: OK, Thank you for your answers... I'll just add new column in A table -> user_id